# Backbone/Marionette - How to listen to events on Region's child view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a View, a CollectionView is rendered inside a region of this View. How do I make View listen to events of CollectionView?

```
const ChildCollectionView = marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    // ...

    events: {
        'click .bar': 'clickBar',
    },

    clickBar() {
        this.trigger('clickBar');
    },
}); 

const ParentView = marionette.View.extend({
    // ...
    regions: {
        foo: '.foo',
    },
    // ...
    onRender() {
        const fooRegion = this.getRegion('foo');

        fooRegion.on('show', function(view) {
            // XXX: this does not work
            view.on('childview:clickBar', function() {
                console.log('click bar');
            });
        });

        fooRegion.show(new ChildCollectionView({
            // ...
        }))
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using Marionette 3.x. In short, you can use [`childViewEvents`](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/events.html#child-view-events).

As to the specifics of your code, it would be better to have the `childView` of your CollectionView define the click event, as the listener to the child view event will receive the childView that was clicked. It would also be better to use the `showChildView` method in the `ParentView`'s onRender.

```js
const ChildView = marionette.View.extend({
    // ...
    triggers: {
        'click .bar': 'click:bar',
    },
    // or
    events: {
        'click .bar': 'clickBar'
    },
    clickBar() {
        // other child view stuff
        this.trigger('click:bar');
    },
});
const ChildCollectionView = marionette.View.extend({
    // ...
    childView: ChildView,
    childViewEvents: {
        'click:bar': 'barClicked',
    },
    barClicked(childView) {
        // other view stuff
        this.trigger('child:clicked:bar', childView);
        // or
        this.triggerMethod('child:clicked:bar', this, childView)
    }
});
const ParentView = marionette.View.extend({
    regions: {
        foo: '.foo'
    },
    childViewEvents: {
        'child:clicked:bar': 'clickBar'
    },
    clickBar(collectionChild, clickedChild) {
        console.log('click bar', collectionChild.cid, clickedChild.model.cid);
    },
    onRender() {
        this.showChildView('foo', new ChildCollectionView());
    }
});
```

See JSFiddle below for different ways to see an example plus a couple different ways to trigger events. (forked from Marionette example)

https://jsfiddle.net/opyfvsfx/36/